# How to write Rails API for steam openid login and authorize feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, openid, steam-web-api

I am trying to write API using rails.
i have used this `gem omniauth-steam`
and i referred this blog.
https://www.sitepoint.com/steam-powered-dota-on-rails/ 
This is fine, works for HTML. when i click on **Login through steam**, i will be redirected to steam site where i should login and authorize the app. it redirects back to my app and everything works fine. 
But when i am trying to api and try the **login via steam** through Postman, i still get HTML response. i even tried setting headers in Postman.

Here is my **routes.rb**

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'api/v1/sessions#create', via: :all
delete '/logout', to: 'api/v1/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
```

The path generated is `localhost:3000/auth/steam` 
Is there a way to get `Json` response and i can **login & authorize application through postman**?

Need help Ty.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to handle these differently based on the format received. You'll need to change your controller methods to something like this.

```
def create
  # your logic here

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      redirect_to path
    end
    format.json { render json: {} } #json structure
  end
end
```

You can use either block formats. `do..end` or `{}`

Comment: Thank u for reply, 
the path generated from oauth to login through steam is `localhost:3000/auth/steam` , when i request this url in postman.. i am getting HTML response.
This is third party link which redirects our page to steam website and allows user to register. It is NOT a HTML created by me.